# PostgreSQL - how do I know which partition I'm in when using window functions?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I've been using windows functions as they're very useful for my current requirement. `row_number()` is very handy for letting me know the row of the current partition.  I've read the documentation on window functions and searched online, but can't find an answer to what I want.  I'm hoping that someone here can tell if what I want is possible.

My question is this: is it possible to find out which partition within a window you are in, in a similar way that `row_number()` tells you which row within the partition you are in?

Basically, I want to know something like this, assuming 2 partitions in the window with 2 rows in each partition:

```
partition 1 row 1
partition 1 row 2
partition 2 row 1
partition 2 row 2
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS col1, 1 AS col2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 3
)

SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) partition1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) partition2
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    col1, col2;
```

[image]

### Demo

The general pattern here, for an arbitrary number of partitions, would be to use `DENSE_RANK` for the first N-1 partitions, and then `ROW_NUMBER` at the last partition.  `ROW_NUMBER` would ensure that the last partition has 1,2,3,... as the sequence.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I'll give that a go.  Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!